# opening deposit boxes

Tags: payday-2

I was playing a round of firestarter, on the day 3, full team
We did it all stealthily and burned the money.

One guy started to sawing the boxes but next thing I knew all the boxes popped open.

One of the guys claims that in mastermind there is a hidden skill that makes unlocking one box opens all the others.

Is it actually a skill or was it a glitch or something?

Answer (score 8):

The guy was a cheater.

There is [no skill](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Skills) in the mastermind tree (or any tree) that allows this.

Answer (score 1):

That guy is definately a cheat or it is a known bug. there is a hack that does this however found here

[LINK to someone using a similar hack](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpw3mRbw_9s)

So unfortunately this is most likely a hacker and i would say don't play with him again[image]